# How to add parameters into PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am very new to Android Programming. I would like to know if it is possible to add extra parameters using PendingIntent ?

For example I wanna do something like intent.putExtra("test", key) in PendingIntent. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters in intent.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class); 
String displayName = "abc"
intent.putExtra("name", displayName); 
PendingIntent pendIt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
        TxrjConstant.REQUEST_READ_NOTIFICATION, 
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```